# Help choosing the optimal time series analysis package

Tags: time-series, forecasting, python, software, exponential-smoothing

I am developing an app for time series analysis that should support the following:

- [Exponential Smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) ([Holt-Winters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Triple_exponential_smoothing_(Holt_Winters)))
- [Box-Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Jenkins_method)
- [curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) (straight line, quadratic, exponential, growth)
- multiple regression
- [Croston's intermittent demand model](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254044245_A_Review_of_Croston%27s_method_for_intermittent_demand_forecasting) and discrete data models
- new product forecasting (Bass diffusion)

Are you familiar with **open source** stat packages other than [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)), that supports these models? ([Python](https://www.python.org/)?)

Comment: Add features that test the normality of the errors which would include 1) Intervention Detection to disclose Pulses/Level Shifts/Seasonal Pulses 2) non-constant variance of the errors due to changes in parameters over time or due to break-points in variance suggesting the need for power transformations and/or Garch .You should also be looking for automatic detection of lead and lag structureSs (PDL) around user-specified causal/regressor series.Additionally being able to sort out the need for ARIMA versus fixed predictors e.g.day-of-the-week would along with optimal ARIMA structure.

Comment: R is really going to be your best bet here for open source.

Comment: @lilile Yes AUTOBOX . Available from Automatic Forecasting Systems .They have 30 day demo available at http://www.autobox.com/30day.exe .

Comment: @lililie I should have mentioned I am one of the developers of this program.

Answer (score 1):

[`pmdarima`](https://pypi.org/project/pmdarima/) gives you (S)ARIMA models, with orders chosen by minimizing [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion). You don't want to do the [Box-Jenkins approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Jenkins_method), [information criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection#Criteria) are superior. [`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) gives you [multiple regression](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/regression.html), which in turn can fit curves. I don't know of a module that does exponential smoothing, Croston's method or Bass models.